# Using message topic in IBM Watson internet of things platform rules

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

we have to use message topic in WIoTP rules. That is if a certain event is triggered X times in Y mins then trigger an action. I am not able to see an option of selecting the message topic while creating a rule. Can someone suggest how this can  be done?

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to select a message topic in the Rules configuration.  The documentation for triggering rules when the conditions are met N times in the selected time interval can be found here:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/cloud_analytics.html#conditional

Comment: Thanks Valerie. Is it possible to create trigger when event is published by a single device. For example if a single device sends event A, 100 times in 10 mins. This is really required to identify and block DoS attacks.

Comment: Rules are defined against certain schema, which is mapping to device type level, this can not be changed.  The real time insights feature transforms statistics by device ID.  It does not mix the data from different device IDs here. If you only want to apply the specific rule to single device ID, one option may be to set the device id in payload and define a rule condition against the device id field in the payload.  I suggest you open a Bluemix support ticket so we can assist you further to help meet your requirements.